# Changing time from 24 hour clock to 12 hour in batch code

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I currently have the following code in a batch file Backup.bat on my desktop. it is used to back up an excel spreadsheet file each day and rename it by appending the current date and time. **File.xlsx** is copied and pasted to a new folder as **File Sun-06-24-2012 23.21.46PM.xlsx**

Currently the date and time is appended as Sun-06-24-2012 **23**.21.46PM.xlsx but i would like to have it append as Sun-06-24-2012 **11**.21.46PM.xlsx using the 12 hour clock rather than 24 hour clock format.

Below is the code i am currently using in Windows XP Professional. Would anyone know how  to have the time appended in 12 hour clock format rather than 24 hour clock format as it is currently in the code below.

```
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @(
Set DayW=%%A
Set Day=%%B
Set Month=%%C
Set Year=%%D
Set All=%%A-%%B-%%C-%%D
)
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:,. " %%A in ('echo %time%') do @(
Set Hour=%%A
Set Min=%%B
Set Sec=%%C
Set Allm=%%A.%%B.%%C
)
@For /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%A in ('time /t ') do @(
Set AMPM=%%A
)

copy "C:\Temp\File.xlsx" "C:\Temp\DailyBackup\File %All% %Allm%%AMPM%.xlsx"
```

Comment: You have an automated backup and choose voluntarily to use a date and time format that's so utterly unusable for that purpose? Yikes.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Joey's comment, I think you are better off with 24 hour format.

Also, your method for getting the date and time will break as soon as the code is transferred to another machine that uses a different date and/or time configuration.

But, here goes anyway...

You should get the entire time string from a single %TIME% expansion. Otherwise you run the risk of getting the hour:min:sec before midnight and the AMPM after midnight.

Put `@ECHO OFF` at the top, then you don't need to sprinkle `@` throughout your code.

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do (
  Set DayW=%%A
  Set Day=%%B
  Set Month=%%C
  Set Year=%%D
  Set All=%%A-%%B-%%C-%%D
)
For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:,. " %%A in ('echo %time%') do (
  set /a "Hour=100%%A%%100"
  set Min=%%B
  set Sec=%%C
)
if %Hour% geq 12 (
  set AMPM=PM
  set /a "Hour-=12"
) else set "AMPM=AM"
if %Hour% equ 0 set "Hour=12"
if %Hour% lss 10 set "Hour=0%Hour%"
set "Allm=%Hour%.%Min%.%Sec%%AMPM%"

echo on
copy "C:\Temp\File.xlsx" "C:\Temp\DailyBackup\File %All% %Allm%.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Time /t` is giving you the time in 24-hour format, presumably because that's the default for your computer's locale.

As `time /t` doesn't appear to offer any formatting options, probably the easiest thing to do is add an extra section to your batch file to convert the 24-hour clock to 12-hour.

Somewhere under `Set Hour=%%A` you just need to:

- Subtract 12 from the hour if it's more than 12
- Change '00' into '12'

For example:

```
If %Hour% gtr 12 (
Set /a Hour=%Hour%-12
)
If %Hour% == 00 (
Set Hour=12
)
```

The /a switch on `Set` tells it that the value to the right of the equals sign is a numerical expression to be evaluated.

This will leave you with no leading zero on the hour if it comes out from 1 to 9. You could get around this with another `if` statement to add a leading zero back in, or there might be a more elegant approach!

Comment: Code fails if Hour is 12 because 0 does not equal 00 (IF does a string comparison if it sees 2 leading zeros)